# Highscore File for a Game

Tags: c#

For my game i have a class "highscores" which holds the code necessary to do the following:
Check if the user has a highscore, if their current in-game score exceeds this replace it.
If they don't have a highscore write the score they just achieved.
This will all be in the format name|highscore.

I currently have done(don't judge new to coding)

```
    public void WriteAllHS()
    {
        if (File.Exists("AllHighscores.txt")) //Check if file exists
        {
            if (Player.score > highscore)    //Check if the new score exceeds the current High score                                                
            {
                string[] FileContents = 
                File.ReadAllLines(@"AllHighscores.txt");
                string[] NS = { "" };       //Removes the |

                for (int l = 0; l < FileContents.Length; l++)
                {
                    NS = FileContents[l].Split('|'); 
                }
                int k = 0;        //check what place in the array the logged in users' highscore is and saves it and checks if they have a highscore at all
                for (int i = 0; i < NS.Length; i = i + 2)
                {
                    if (Player.name == NS[i])
                    {
                        k = i;
                        check = true;
                    }
                }

                //If they have a highscore and their new score is bigger it will: 1)delete the file 2)replace the old high score with the new bigger one 3)Writes all high scores to the new file

                if (check == true && Convert.ToInt32(NS[k+1]) < Player.score)
                {
                    File.Delete("AllHighscores.txt");
                    NS[k+1] = Convert.ToString(Player.score);
                    for (int a = 0; a < NS.Length; a = a + 2)
                    {
                        string[] holder = new string[2];
                        holder[0] = NS[a];
                        holder[1] = NS[a + 1];
                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"AllHighscores.txt", true))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(holder[0] + "|" + holder[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            if (check == false)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"AllHighscores.txt", true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(Player.name + "|" + Player.score);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"AllHighscores.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(Player.name + "|" + Player.score);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Currently it will replace the score in the file for 1 user, but if tried for another user it will delete all users high scores apart from the newly written one. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see an actual question in all of the above. Please reduce your code to a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces or clearly illustrates whatever problem or difficulty it is you have. Explain precisely what the code does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: I think you are trying to add new line in your text file. If that is the case then you should use File.AppendAllText